# how to store null values in listbox c#

Tags: c#, mysql, listbox

I'm developing a windows store app and it has many list boxes to retrieve data from database,
Here is my MySQL Database screenshot

[image]

After that Null value in the database listboxes are not filling with data as shown as following screenshot

[image]

I want to keep that Null values as empty in the list box and store other details How can I do that

here is the C# code

```
 private void Button_View_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listb0.Items.Clear();
        listb1.Items.Clear();
        listb2.Items.Clear();
        listb3.Items.Clear();
        listb4.Items.Clear();            
        try
        {
            string Query = @"SELECT * FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_results`;";
            //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;
            conn.Open();
            MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();// this query will be executed and data saved into the database.           
            while (MyReader.Read())
            {
                ListBoxItem itm0 = new ListBoxItem();
                itm0.Content = MyReader.GetString(0);
                this.listb0.Items.Add(itm0);

                ListBoxItem itm1 = new ListBoxItem();
                itm1.Content = MyReader.GetString(1);
                this.listb1.Items.Add(itm1);

                ListBoxItem itm2 = new ListBoxItem();
                itm2.Content = MyReader.GetString(2);
                this.listb2.Items.Add(itm2);

                ListBoxItem itm3 = new ListBoxItem();
                itm3.Content = MyReader.GetString(3);
                this.listb3.Items.Add(itm3);

                ListBoxItem itm4 = new ListBoxItem();
                itm4.Content = MyReader.GetString(4);
                this.listb4.Items.Add(itm4);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to work about this issue in code you need to check for DBNull using the DBNull method of the DataReader

```
ListBoxItem itm2 = new ListBoxItem();
itm2.Content = MyReader.IsDBNull(2) ? "" : MyReader.GetString(2);
this.listb2.Items.Add(itm2);
```

Of course this pattern should be applied to other columns that could be potentially null.

Comment: Can you tell me the error message displayed by the errormsgBox call?

Comment: no errors showing but its not filling after that null value as shown as above screenshot

Comment: Try to change your catch with `catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `IFNULL(<colName>,'Defaultvalue')`, so that if there is `null` value in DB, it will have some default value in select query result.

In your case, Query ( select query) will be like this

```
"SELECT tbl_subject_sub_id, reg_id, ifnull(type,'') type,status,grade  FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_results`;"
```

Comment: this not working, nothing is filled in the listboxes

Comment: are you able to run this query in mysql console, and see, if that returns any result?

Comment: Is this still shows incomplete listbox, if so then use some value instead of blank values ,i mean use this - `ifnull(type,'some_type')` .

Comment: here is the code whi i try `SELECT
tbl_subject_sub_id,
reg_id,
ifnull(type,'some_type')type,
status,
grade
FROM tbl_results;` its working only in mysql workbench and its work in app

Comment: Is the behavior is still same?

Comment: this method doesn't work in the app by the way thanks i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
if(MyReader.GetString(index) == null)
{
   // do stuff !
}
```

You should check for null values `MyReader.GetString.` You can check also `string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyReader.GetString(index))`